# Does a cookie's content become part of the request header always?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, request-headers

The search application I am working on allows a user to select the results and export them in different formats like EXCEL, XML etc.

The unique id of the selected results are stored in a cookie, using JavaScript, so that later this information can be posted to export the search results.

The problem is - when the content of the cookie becomes fairly large, the Web Application Firewall blocks the requests. On analyzing, I see that all cookie content becomes part of the request header making it over the size allowed by the firewall.

Is this behavior same for all cookies? What would be the suggested work around in such scenarios?

Technology is ASP.NET 4.0, on IIS 7.5 server.

Comment: Normally a unique id to identify some results would be quite small (e.g. a 64 bit number). Are you actually storing the full results in the cookie instead?

Comment: @Daniel:The unique id in this case is a 6 digit number, and the problem occurs when there are around 100 of them

Comment: So it's a set of unique ids, one for each search result, rather than a single unique id representing the set of all results? If so, can't you do the later?

Comment: @Daniel: You are right. It is a set of unique ids, one for each result. Probably I need a kind of solution as you suggest. But, I am not sure how to maintain the search results unique ids. Do you mean to keep a single unique id and save the search results unique ids in a database against it (for each select/unselect operation) ?

Comment: You probably want something stateless on the server-side, so how about storing the query, or just enough information to recompose the query, in the cookie?

Comment: @Daniel: The user is at liberty to choose any search result he wants to export (even through multiple pages). So, we don't want all of them. I suppose that was the idea in storing the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the cookies will be included in every request to the server when the URL matches the cookie's path.

Given that the user can select arbitrary items to be exported later, you need to store the IDs for those items somewhere.

Storing them in plain text, in a cookie, is obviously causing a problem with the firewall. One option to avoid this is to compress the IDs. For example, if the IDs are `123456`, `123459`, `123463` then you really only need to store 123456;3;4 (the lowest number, and the increments) but this form can be difficult to process and will only benefit in some cases.

Another option would be to compress the cookie data using, for example, the gzip format. But this may not be straightforward if writing the cookie using JavaScript (although you might get away with writing only the items on the current page in plain text and having the server compress them as the user moves between pages).

If the quantity of data in the cookie remains too large you could look into server-side state, using a database for example. A table with `ExportId` and `ItermId` columns where you add or remove rows according to the user's actions and only need to send `ExportId` in the URL or cookie.

Comment: you mention that the cookies will be included in every request when the URL matches the cookie's path. So, is it possible that if I store the cookie in a fictitious path, they are not passed along in the request? Using the jQuery cookie plugin For e.g. $.cookie('cookieName','cookiValue', {path: '/abc'});

Comment: Yes, but you'll still need a way to communicate all that data to the server (e.g. via Post data).